# How to use NGXS with route resolvers?

Tags: angular, ngxs

Assuming I've got a CRUD application which manages articles. What's the correct way to make use of NGXS **in combination** with route parameters?

When I open the application I'm at `/`. Clicking on a button takes me to `/articles`:

- what happens now? Do I need a route resolver which dispatches an NGXS action to load articles or is the container component for articles responsible for that?
- when the list of articles has been loaded (by a resolver or the container itself) I want to click on a specific article which takes me to `/articles/1` for example. Again: do I need a route resolver here?

If I need route resolvers: how to show loading spinners in specific components while the state is being loaded (e.g. showing a spinner within the article list)? The only possible solution to that would be returning an `Observable<Observable>` from the resolver.

If no: if I directly head to `/articles/1` who's gonna dispatch necessary actions for my state to be correct (in this case the articles itself hasn't been loaded, so how should one specific article be loaded)?

I couldn't find any resources regarding this topic. All example apps I've found don't mind the current route which would lead to pretty bad UX imo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How to use NGXS with route resolvers?

Very easy :D `store.dispatch` returns an observable, which will generate an event and complete after all asyncronous work is done, so you can easily dispatch actions in resolvers.

Assume you've got an action called `GetArticles`:

```js
export class GetArticles {
  public static readonly type = '[Articles] Get articles';
}
```

You would want to have a state where you'd store all your articles and also an action handler that responds to the `GetArticles`:

```js
@State({
  name: 'articles',
  defaults: []
})
export class ArticlesState {
  constructor(private articlesService: ArticlesService) {}

  @Action(GetArticles)
  public getArticles(ctx: StateContext<Article[]>) {
    return this.articlesService.getArticles().pipe(
      tap(articles => {
        ctx.setState(articles);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

So what you've got to do is to create a resolver, dispatch an action there and map the stream to the articles array, something like that:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ArticlesResolver implements Resolve<Article[]> {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  public resolve() {
    return this.store.dispatch(new GetArticles()).pipe(
      map(() => this.store.selectSnapshot(ArticlesState))
    );
  }
}
```

That's it, your `ArticlesComponent` already can access pre-loaded articles via `ActivatedRoute.prototype.snapshot.data.articles` (assuming you've linked resolver with component like `resolve: { articles: ArticlesResolver }`).

---

Considering your question about routing to the specific article like `/articles/1`, if you already pre-loaded your articles - couldn't you get the necessary article directly from `articles` array? You can create a selector which will search for the article by `id`:

```js
export class ArticlesState {
  public static getArticleById(id: string) {
    return createSelector(
      [ArticlesState],
      (articles: Article[]) => articles.find(article => article.id === id)
    );
  }
}
```

So all you've got to do in your `ArticleComponent` is just select a snapshot from the store by calling this selector factory with `id`:

```js
export class ArticleComponent {
  public article: Article = this.store.selectSnapshot(
    ArticlesState.getArticleById(this.route.snapshot.params.id)
  );

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private store: Store) {}
}
```

Comment: What a brilliant answer! +1

Comment: While I love this method of dispatching actions to set state in resolvers. It seems weird to me that the resolve property in the RouterModule actually creates the object on ActivatedRoute.data (resolve: { something: MyResolver }). Its pointless to have that data just lingering there if you never use it as its on your state once dispatched. I realize thats just the way the resolvers work, but you would think the angular team would at least make something that allowed you to resolve this without the need to use memory by putting the results on ActivatedRoute.data.